# Split string into parts of varying lengths

Tags: strings, f#

I need to split a string into parts of varying predefined lengths, given as a sequence of integers. After a first imperative attempt using a sequence expression and a reference cell, I have now come up with this implementation that uses `Seq.scan` and doesn't need mutability:

```
let segmentString lengths (input : string) =
    let folder (start, parts) lengthHere = 
        let partHere = input.Substring(start, lengthHere)
        start + lengthHere, partHere :: parts

    let results = lengths |> Seq.scan folder (0, [])

    let _, resultParts = Seq.last results
    List.rev resultParts
```

This works and is probably "good enough", but I wonder whether there are things that could be improved or more idiomatic (other than error handling and allowing more generic inputs than strings; I left those out because they are not a concern right now). What especially bugs me is the need to reverse the results list at the end, but obviously, I could only add the new part as the head of the aggregate list in the `folder` function.

Comment: What should it do when the sum of `lengths` is smaller than the length of `input`? Just ignore the rest of the `input`, like your code does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty good solution but like you say, the reverse is annoying, so let's see if we can fix that.

We want a sequence of tuples `(start, length)` that we can pass to `Substring`. We already have the lengths, so we just need to figure out the starts. The skeleton of our solution looks like this:

```
let segmentString lengths (input : string) =
    let segments = Seq.zip ??? lengths
    Seq.map (input.Substring : int * int -> string) segments
```

So where does a segment start? It starts at the sum of the previous lengths. We can use `scan (+) 0` to calculate the partial sums of the lengths.

This gives us the final solution

```
let segmentString lengths (input : string) =
    let segments = Seq.zip (Seq.scan (+) 0 lengths) lengths
    Seq.map (input.Substring : int * int -> string) segments
```

Comment: That is the more functional solution I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that reversing by using manual recursion:

```
let segmentString lengths (input : string) =
    let rec segmentString' start = function
        | [] -> []
        | length::lengthsTail ->
            let segment = input.Substring(start, length)
            let segmentsTail = segmentString' (start + length) lengthsTail
            segment::segmentsTail

    segmentString' 0 (List.ofSeq lengths)
```

I'm generally not in favor of using recursion directly, most of the time, you should use higher-order functions instead. But here, that higher-order function would be a hybrid between `fold` and `foldBack` (state has to be computed front to back, but result back to front), so I think that recursion makes sense here.